# Where can I find Generic Figures and Their Gluings?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, category-theory, topos-theory

I have read the sample pages for *Generic Figures and Their Gluings* on [the authors' website](https://reyes-reyes.com/2004/06/01/generic-figures-and-their-glueings-a-constructive-approach-to-functor-categories/), and I was really enjoying it. The book appears to be out of print, and I can't find the authors' emails in order to request a copy. Does anyone know where this book can be found?

Comment: I'd check some libraries. Also. https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Z5GcOhfwoD0C&oi=fnd&pg=PA9&dq=Generic+Figures+and+Their+Gluings&ots=_rp4AL0INd&sig=8WMyfZQPk07XEUR6dC57ZDy9WHY#v=onepage&q=Generic%20Figures%20and%20Their%20Gluings&f=false.

Comment: I will try that at the nearby universities. I'm very mobile right now so having a mobile copy would be best.

Comment: I don't speak the language, but I believe you can contact the author directly https://reyes-reyes.com and ask for a pdf version.

Comment: I had trouble figuring out how to do so from that site. Is there somethingb obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Done, thanks Will

Comment: "Where can I find an illuminating discussion of such-and-such mathematical topic" is appropriate for this site, but "where can I locate a particular book" isn't. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2006) Meta answer.

Comment: Where would you suggest I ask instead?

Comment: Doesn't seem any of the SE websites would be appropriate. It could go in the chat, or going by your profile, to the librarians at your institution. // By the way, your first port of call for finding a book should be [worldcat.org](http://www.worldcat.org/title/generic-figures-and-their-glueings-a-constructive-approach-to-functor-categories/oclc/494044198). It lists two libraries in the US with the book.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into those libraries.